# Analyzing C# VS Solution using SonarQube, MSBuild14 and FxCop10

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, fxcop

I am in a Team that currently uses VS2013, so my installation is MSBuild12.
I installed [FXCop10](https://fxcopinstaller.codeplex.com/). 
I installed [MSBuild14](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159). 
I installed [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

I run SonarQube Version 5.6 in the demo mode.
I have all rules enables and can analyse using the following batch script:

```
<!-- language: lang-sh-->
@echo off
REM Set FxCop10Directory="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\"
REM Set FxCop10="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe"

Set ScannerDirectory="D:\Programs\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\bin\"
Set MSBuild12="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Set MSBuild14="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Set Runner="MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe"
Set Key="DEMO2016"
Set Name="SonarQube Internal Demo"
Set Version="0.0.0.0"

PATH=%PATH%;%ScannerDirectory%

call %Runner% begin /k:%Key% /n:%Name% /v:%Version%
call %MSBuild14% /t:Rebuild
call %Runner% end
pause
```

When I try to upgrade to MSBuild14 by changing my call to call `%MSBuild14% /t:Rebuild`, I get an error.

```
error : FxCop must be installed when some of its rules are enabled in the SonarQube quality profile. FxCop is included as part of Visual Studio.
```

VS2013 came with another Version of FXCop.

How can I control the Version used by the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner`?
How do I set up FxCop10 for the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why MSBuild12 initially worked for me.
I had to import the development environment to make things work on my system.

```
<!-- language: none-->

@echo off
echo.
echo Setup References
Set ScannerDirectory="D:\Programs\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\bin\"
Set MSBuild14="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Set Runner="MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe"
Set vcvars="C:\LegacyApp\VisualStudio2013\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
echo.
echo Setup Runner Parameters
Set Key="DEMO2016"
Set Name="SonarQube Internal Demo"
Set Version="0.0.0.0"
echo.
echo Create Environment
PATH=%PATH%;%ScannerDirectory%
call %vcvars%
echo.
echo Runner Begin
call %Runner% begin /k:%Key% /n:%Name% /v:%Version%
echo.
echo MSBuild Rebuild
call %MSBuild14% /t:Rebuild
echo.
echo Runner End
call %Runner% end
pause
```

The output shows where the Currently used FxCop Version is:

```
<!-- language: none-->

Running Code Analysis...
C:\LegacyApp\VisualStudio2013\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe
```

Executing that file in a command prompt returns its Version.